# Facebook custom share alternative to feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

Hi i'm working on a test site to share personalized content non linked to og.

I'm at the point that i have implement the FB.ui method feed but i read that it's deprecated.
So i have looked for the new share_open_graph with object and action.

Now i can create an action and share it, but when i share it don't appear in the board but only in the timeline. and as i read on the rules this function make 2 call that can be passible to ban/suspension.

the site is:
[www.paris-web.it/test.html](http://www.paris-web.it/test.html)

you can see all the code directy in page/with inspector

```
function postLike(){
 accessToken = FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
 FB.api(
'me/objects/article',
'post',
{
object: {
    "app_id": fbAppId,
    "type": "article",
    "url": objectToLike,
    "title": "my title",
    "image": logoImage,
    "description": "my desc",
    "expiration_time": "2014-07-23"
    }
},
function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if ( response.error != undefined ){
      $("#result").text(response.error.message);
      return;
    }else{
      $("#result").text("succesfull shared "+response.id);
    }

    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: response.id
         })
    }, function(r){});
});
}
```

i'm looking for some solution/alternative and with some example. i'm blocked there from 3 day and i can't find any other solution.

tHANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with a dynamic url that generate dynamic og via php.

It's the only solution to have personalizedcontent and don't have problem with google/facebook cache!

You can see the result on the same page linked in OP